# Windows 10 does not boot after grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

I first installed windows 10, and then Ubuntu 19.02. Ubuntu was installed using an USB created by Rufus.

GRUB is shown, but when I select "Windows", grub is loaded again.

I've performed `bootinfoscript`, and you can find output information on [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1915662) (Please, ignore `/dev/sdb` disk information, it only contains an old windows instalation).

Could you tell what's wrong?

My `/dev/sda` disk partitions currently are:

```
Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,085,439     1,083,392 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2       1,085,440     1,290,239       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3       1,290,240     1,323,007        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda4       1,323,008 1,298,163,711 1,296,840,704 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5   1,298,163,712 1,310,162,943    11,999,232 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda6   1,310,162,944 1,953,523,711   643,360,768 Data partition (Linux)
```

My current `/boot/grup/grub.cfg` related windows entry is:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-40A3-A42A' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  40A3-A42A
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 40A3-A42A
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

You can find complete current `grub.cfg` content on [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1915827).

Comment: You installed Windows in BIOS boot mode on sdb, and Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on sda. They need to be in same boot mode, unless you always want to boot from UEFI boot menu. Once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub can only offer to boot other systems in same boot mode. I would reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode, if new install. How you boot install media for both Ubuntu & Windows UEFI or BIOS, is then how it installs. And Windows only boots in UEFI boot mode from gpt, your sdb is MBR(msdos), so has to be BIOS boot.

Comment: Sorry, could you ignore `/dev/sdb` related information? This disk contains an old windows installation. Could you check on post edit?